# Given $h$ and bases $\mathcal A, \mathcal B$ , find the representation matrices $A$,$B$, and the matrix $P$ such that $B=PAP^{-1}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, change-of-basis

For the homomorphism $h: \mathcal P_2 \rightarrow \mathcal P_2$  given by

$1 \mapsto 3$, $x \mapsto 2x-1$, $x^2 \mapsto x^2-x-1$

(i) Find the matrix $A=Rep_{\mathcal{A,A}}(h)$ for basis $\mathcal A= \langle1,x,x^2\rangle$

(ii) Find the matrix $B=Rep_{\mathcal{B,B}}(h)$ for basis $\mathcal B= \langle1,1+x,1+x+x^2\rangle$

(iii) Find the matrix $P$ such that $B=PAP^{-1}$.

For context, we are doing a unit on determinants, and this is an undergraduate linear algebra class. Here's my attempt at (i) and (ii), which is as far as I got:

(i) I start by evaluating $h(\mathcal A)$

$h(\vec a_1)=h(1)=3$

$h(\vec a_2)=h(x)=2x-1$

$h(\vec a_3)=h(x^2)=x^2-x-1$

Then, for $A=Rep_{\mathcal{A,A}}(h)$ I have:

$A = 
    \begin{pmatrix}\\
    Rep_{\mathcal A}(3) & Rep_{\mathcal A}(2x-1) & Rep_{\mathcal A}(x^2-x-1) \\
    \\
    \end{pmatrix}$ $= \begin{pmatrix}
    3 & -1 & -1 \\
    0 & 2 & -1 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}$

Please tell me if I've calculated each respective representation right, because I fear that I've already messed up here.

(ii) Here, following the same process, I get:

$ B= \begin{pmatrix}\\
    Rep_{\mathcal B}(3) & Rep_{\mathcal B}(2x+2) & Rep_{\mathcal B}(x^2+x+1) \\
    \\ \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
    3 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 2 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}$

Am I on the right track? Furthermore, *how should I go about (iii)*? I am not sure how to approach it but I assume it has to do with the properties of determinants in one way or another.

Thanks!!